# select in json jquery manuplation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to add data into a table using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#imgprogress').show();
        var url = 'DocumentsList';  //definitly it was writtern as Url.Action
        var tr;
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                tr = $('<tr>');
                tr.append("<td width='10%'>" + item.id + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>")
                if (item.status == "") {
                    tr.append("<select><option value='' selected></option>")
                }
                else {
                    tr.append("<select><option value=''></option>")
                }

                if (item.status == "Stored in London") {
                    tr.append("<option value='Stored in London' selected>Stored in London</option>")
                }
                else {
                    tr.append("<option value='Stored in London'>Stored in London</option>")
                }
                if (item.status == "Sent to Institution") {
                    tr.append("<option value='Sent to Institution'  selected>Sent to Institution</option>")
                }
                else {
                    tr.append("<option value='Sent to Institution'>Sent to Institution</option>")
                }
                if (item.status == "Destroyed") {
                    tr.append("<option value='Destroyed' selected>Destroyed</option>")
                }
                else {
                    tr.append("<option value='Destroyed'>Destroyed</option>")
                }
                if (item.status == "Post to London") {
                    tr.append("<option value='Post to London'  selected>Post to London</option>")
                }
                else {
                    tr.append("<option value='Post to London'>Post to London</option>")
                }
                if (item.status == "Returned to client") {
                    tr.append("<option value='Returned to client' selected>Returned to client</option>")
                }
                else {
                    tr.append("<option value='Returned to client'>Returned to client</option>")
                }
                if (item.status == "Post to Richmond") {
                    tr.append("<option value='Post to Richmond' selected>Post to Richmond</option></select>")
                }
                else {
                    tr.append("<option value='Post to Richmond'>Post to Richmond</option></select>")
                }
                tr.append("</td>");
                tr.append("</tr>");
                $('#tblClientDocument').append(tr);
            });
        });
    });
```

The above doesn't seems to work can some one help me?

I have a table define and I am trying to insert each row into the table from a result in json, the  is created and the options outside. I don't understand why

out put (single row)

```
<tr class="odd"><td width="10%" class=" sorting_1">8206</td><td class=" "></td><select><option value=""></option></select><option value="Stored in London" selected="">Stored in London</option><option value="Sent to Institution">Sent to Institution</option><option value="Destroyed">Destroyed</option><option value="Post to London">Post to London</option><option value="Returned to client">Returned to client</option><option value="Post to Richmond">Post to Richmond</option><td class=" ">Certified copy of SSE bill</td><td class=" "></td><td class=" "></td><td class=" ">Utility Bill / Statement</td><td class=" ">22/11/2013 00:00:00</td></tr>
```

Comment: Did you try running this code in a debugger to see exactly what happens when you run it?

Comment: Also, can you show what HTML is being generated?

Comment: pasted the result below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because the data you're appending is not valid html.

I would try to separate the html elements:

```
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td width='10%'>" + item.id + "</td>");
        td = $("<td/>");
        select = $("<select/>");
        if (item.status == "") {
            select.append("<option value='' selected></option>")
        }
        else {
            select.append("<option value=''></option>")
        }

        ...

        if (item.status == "Post to Richmond") {
            select.append("<option value='Post to Richmond' selected>Post to Richmond</option>")
        }
        else {
            select.append("<option value='Post to Richmond'>Post to Richmond</option>")
        }
        td.append(select);
        tr.append(td);
        $('#tblClientDocument').append(tr);
```

Answer (score -1):

see the commented part

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#imgprogress').show();
var url = 'DocumentsList';  //definitly it was writtern as Url.Action
var tr;
$.get(url, null, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        tr = $('<tr>');
        tr.append("<td width='10%'>" + item.id + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>")
        if (item.status == "") {
            tr.append("<select><option value='' selected></option>")
        }
        else {
            tr.append("<select><option value=''></option>")
        }


        // also you do not append the options as children of the select but as siblings of them which wont work


        if (item.status == "Stored in London") {
            tr.append("<option value='Stored in London' selected>Stored in London</option>")
        }
        else {
            tr.append("<option value='Stored in London'>Stored in London</option>")
        }
        if (item.status == "Sent to Institution") {
            tr.append("<option value='Sent to Institution'  selected>Sent to Institution</option>")
        }
        else {
            tr.append("<option value='Sent to Institution'>Sent to Institution</option>")
        }
        if (item.status == "Destroyed") {
            tr.append("<option value='Destroyed' selected>Destroyed</option>")
        }
        else {
            tr.append("<option value='Destroyed'>Destroyed</option>")
        }
        if (item.status == "Post to London") {
            tr.append("<option value='Post to London'  selected>Post to London</option>")
        }
        else {
            tr.append("<option value='Post to London'>Post to London</option>")
        }
        if (item.status == "Returned to client") {
            tr.append("<option value='Returned to client' selected>Returned to client</option>")
        }
        else {
            tr.append("<option value='Returned to client'>Returned to client</option>")
        }
        if (item.status == "Post to Richmond") {
            tr.append("<option value='Post to Richmond' selected>Post to Richmond</option></select>")
        }
        else {
            tr.append("<option value='Post to Richmond'>Post to Richmond</option></select>")
        }
        tr.append("</td>");
        tr.append("</tr>");
        $('#tblClientDocument').append(tr);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: <td class=" "></td><select><option value=""></option></select><option value="Stored in London" selected="">Stored in London</option><option value="Sent to Institution">Sent to Institution</option><option value="Destroyed">Destroyed</option><option value="Post to London">Post to London</option><option value="Returned to client">Returned to client</option><option value="Post to Richmond">Post to Richmond</option>

Comment: a result the is's are triggering, and it is not putting it at the right please

Comment: // also you do not append the options as children of the select but as siblings of them which wont work -- > can you give me a example? @john Smith